# Checking headers with an ERROR. Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, fastify

I ran into a problem when working with headers, when I send in the header 'apiKey', it gives me: `Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'\n    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'\n    --- property 'socket' closes the circle`
I've tried everything and can't find the error. I wrote a module. But it gets an error too.
Look at my code below

```
const fp = require('fastify-plugin')

function headersPlugin(fastify, options, next) {

    fastify.addHook('onRequest', (request, res, next) => {
        const headerName = options.headerName
        console.log(options)

        if(options.convertType) {
            const converted = convert(headerValue, options.convertType)
            request.headers[headerName] = converted
        }

        if(options.transformations) {
            options.transformations.forEach(transform => {
                headerValue = transform(headerValue)
                request.headers[headerName] = JSON.stringify(headerValue)
            })
        }

        next()
    })

    next()
}

module.exports = fp(headersPlugin, {
    name: 'headers-plugin'
})
// connect
fastify.register(headersPlugin, {
headerName: 'apiKey',
})
```

And even so

```
// auth-plugin.js
function authPlugin(fastify, options) {
    fastify.addHook('onRequest', async (request, reply, done) => {
        if (request.method === 'POST') {
            const apiKey = request.headers['apiKey'];
            const validApiKey = options.apiKey;

            if (!apiKey || apiKey !== validApiKey) {
                reply.code(401).send({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
            } else {
                done()
            }
        }
    });
}

module.exports = authPlugin;
// connect
fastify.register(headersPlugin)
```

If I even just output to the console what header came in, I will get errors. 
version fastify: last

Comment: how do you initialize your fastify server? `const fastify = require('fastify')()`?

Comment: Yes. That's how it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a small server based on your example everything is working fine

sever.js

```
const fastify = require('fastify')()

// connect
fastify.register(require('./plug'), {headerName: 'apiKey',})

fastify.listen({ port: 3000 })
```

plug.js

```
const fp = require('fastify-plugin')

function headersPlugin(fastify, options, next) {

fastify.addHook('onRequest', (request, res, next) => {
    const headerName = options.headerName
    console.log(options)

    if(options.convertType) {
        const converted = convert(headerValue, options.convertType)
        request.headers[headerName] = converted
    }

    if(options.transformations) {
        options.transformations.forEach(transform => {
            headerValue = transform(headerValue)
            request.headers[headerName] = JSON.stringify(headerValue)
        })
    }

      next()
  })

  next()
}

 module.exports = fp(headersPlugin, {
     name: 'headers-plugin'
})
```

then `node server.js`

Comment: // I solved the problem. there was a variable not initiated